# How can I have a bar next to python seaborn heatmap which shows the summation of row values?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, visualization, heatmap, seaborn

I am able to generate a heatmap with quantity overlaid on the graphic as a visual of a pivot table. I would like to have a column next to the heatmap which shows the summation of rows and I would like to have a row under the heatmap that shows the summation of columns.

Is there a way to incorporate this into the heatmap figure? `pv` is my pivot table which I use to generate the heatmap figure. I would like to have a column on the right of the chart which has the summed values for each row. Likewise, I would like to have a row on the bottom of the chart which has the summed values for each column.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
mask = np.zeros_like(pv)
mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask)] = True
#with sns.axes_style("white"):
ax = sns.heatmap(pv, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu",mask=mask, linecolor='b', cbar = False)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image: Nevada Chart Output]

Comment: use `plt.subplots` to create a figure with two axes, pass the left Axes to `heatmap`, draw your bars on the right.

Comment: The pandas pivot table function has a `margins` parameter, maybe you want to use that?

Answer (score 14):

@Paul H subplot suggestion did work for my purposes. The code below got me the figure shown. Not sure if this is the most resource efficient method but it got me what I needed. [image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((20,20), (0,0), colspan=19, rowspan=19)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((20,20), (19,0), colspan=19, rowspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((20,20), (0,19), colspan=1, rowspan=19)

mask = np.zeros_like(pv)
mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask)] = True

sns.heatmap(pv, ax=ax1, annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu",mask=mask, linecolor='b', cbar = False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.set_xticklabels(pv.columns,rotation=40)

sns.heatmap((pd.DataFrame(pv.sum(axis=0))).transpose(), ax=ax2,  annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", cbar=False, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(pv.sum(axis=1)), ax=ax3,  annot=True, cmap="YlGnBu", cbar=False, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
```

Comment: Hi JL1515, I tried to use your solution on a different dataset. somehow the annotations on the two sum subplots don't show. any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Wevers did you place annot=True ?